# Comparing year in MySQL while loop

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have searched and searched but still can't find the right way to compare year in MySQL's stored procedure and it always looping forever. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE date_ DATE; 
DECLARE year_ YEAR DEFAULT in_year;
SET date_ = MAKEDATE(in_year, 1);
WHILE (year_ = in_year) DO
--
-- some working code
--
SET date_ = ADDDATE(date_, 1);
SET year_ = YEAR(date_);
END WHILE;
END;
```

The loop should end when the `year_` increases and is not equal to `in_year`. Any solution please? `in_year` is from a function parameter.

Comment: The code looks like it should do what you describe. Maybe you do something to `date_` in the working code? If not, maybe debug the values (e.g. print out `date_` and `year_`) to see what is going on in detail.

Comment: What if you make `year_` an `INT`? _Also, why did you omit the function/proc header?_ Is it possible something in "some working code" is modifying `date_`?

Comment: @Solarflare In my experience, MySQL does not have very good debug tools for routines; however, the questioner could try inserting values at various stages into a logging table to get a peek at what is going on inside it.

Comment: I has tried `INT` still not working. I just doing `SELECT` and `INSERT` and not modifying the `date_`.

Comment: `ADDDATE` adds a day; is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally just found a working alternative to this:

```
WHILE (year_ - in_year = 0) DO
```